# 2 Servers & 1 Client (Mini home internet project)

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, windows-7-x64

I have a school project I need to do but can't find any tutorials on how to do it. I've installed Win Server 2008 on VMWare Fusion 7 on my Macbook Pro. I also installed Windows 7 64bit on VMWare Fusion that will be the client. Now I need to copy my Win Server 2008 & install that onto VMWare Fusion as well. The problem begins with me having to connect the 2 servers together (through DHCP or something?) then be able to connect the client to either server. The teacher will then turn off one of the servers & the client has to automatically connect to the 2nd, still turned on, server. That's the entire project.
Can someone please link a tutorial for this? I must be writing my requests into google incorrectly, because I can't find anything to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of tutorial about that out there, just use keyword "windows server 2008 failover". I had done that with a client-server apps & database running on the server and the client only has 2-3 second connection down and then it's automatically re-connecting to the other server and the apps still running smoothly.